# Spring retry find the last retry

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-integration, spring-retry

I am using [Spring-retry-1.2.0](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry/blob/master/README.md), Retry is working fine, but in my method i want to find it out whether the retrial is the last retrial or not, Is there any method available to get the retrialCount or last retrial in spring-retry?

**Retrial.java**

```
public class Offers extends SimpleRetryPolicy {

@Async
@Retryable(maxAttemptsExpression = "#{retrial.times}", backoff = @Backoff(delayExpression = "#{retrial.delay}"))
public void handleOfferes(Data data) {

 AlwaysRetryPolicy policy = new AlwaysRetryPolicy();
        RetryContext context = policy.open(null);
        System.out.println("context.getRetryCount()::"+context.getRetryCount()); //Always logs 0 even if it retries 2 to 3 times...
        System.out.println("Can retry::"+canRetry(context)); //Always true
//Business Logic
//Get the last count and update the DB ...retrial is ends with failure
}


@Override
public boolean canRetry(RetryContext context) {
    System.out.println("context.getRetryCount()::"+context.getRetryCount());
    System.out.println("getMaxAttempts::"+getMaxAttempts());
    return context.getRetryCount() < getMaxAttempts();
}
}
```

**Changes made after Artem Bilan comments**

**RetryConfiguration**

```
@Configuration
public class RetryConfiguration {

@Value("${retrial.times}")
private Long delayExpression;

@Value("${retrial.delay}")
private int maxAttempts;

@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = "retryInterceptor")
public RetryOperationsInterceptor retryInterceptor() {
    return RetryInterceptorBuilder
            .stateless()
            .backOffOptions(0L,
                    0.0D, delayExpression)
            .maxAttempts(maxAttempts).build();
}
}
```

**Offers.java**

```
@Service
public class Offers {
@Async
@Retryable(interceptor = "retryInterceptor")
public void handleDeviceStatus(Data data) {
//Here how shall i get the retrial count...

}
```

Any help would be appreciable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you need is called `@Recover` (`RecoveryCallback` if without annotations):

```
@Retryable(RemoteAccessException.class)
public void service() {
    // ... do something
}
@Recover
public void recover(RemoteAccessException e) {
   // ... panic
}
```

See the same [README](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry/blob/master/README.md) and [test-case](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/retry/annotation/RecoverAnnotationRecoveryHandlerTests.java) on the matter.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply...But i couldn't get what you are trying to say? Inside the method i just want to know the retrial is the last retrial ?

Comment: There is no such a high level API to track retry attempts. The closest one is `@Recover` which is called when all retry attempts are exhausted. What you need can be reached via `RetryPolicy.canRetry(RetryContext context)` method implementation, but for this purpose you have to configure `RetryOperationsInterceptor` manually and only via manual configuration of the `RetryTemplate` you can inject custom `RetryPolicy` to be able to track `RetryContext.getRetryCount()`

Comment: so via manual configuration can i get the last count inside my method ?Do you have any use-case link for this ? What is the purpose of RetryStatistics.java i can see count related methods in this interface.Also i can see "getRetryCount" method in RetryContext.Are we able to use those methods inside Retryable method ?

Comment: No, we can't use those feature in the `@Retyable`. That isn't its responsibility. The `RetryStatistics` isn't related to the question at all.

Comment: So the only way is to i have to create a custom Retry template ? I think i don't require @Recover ...I just want to update a flag in my code if it is last step if that is possible via custom retry template then i will do it...

Comment: Yeah... Something like that. But you don't need custom `RetryTemplate`, only `RetryPolicy` is enough.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your reply...could you please share a link for creating custom RetryPolicy ?

Comment: Just scan test-cases: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry/tree/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/retry/policy. There is nothing critical for you. You can just extends standard `SimpleRetryPolicy` and override its `canRetry()` for your logic.

Comment: Thanks alot for all your messages..I have edited my question....context.getRetryCount() always returns zero even after 2 to 3-retries...I am getting the valid maxAttemps count but how can we the retrialCount ? Suppose if the spring-retry retries the method for second time then i would expect it should return 2 not 0.

Comment: maxAttemps also i am not getting the configured one it is returning the default max-attempts which is 3

Comment: No, you didn't understand. You have to configure `RetryOperationsInterceptor` instead of raw `@Retriable` options. And only there you can use your custom `RetryPolicy`.

Comment: I can see the following link http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.springframework.retry.interceptor.RetryOperationsInterceptor for implementing retryOperations....After implementing this interceptor do we need to annotate the methods with @ Retriable? Otherwise how it would identify the methods to retry...

Comment: True, you still need to do that. There is an `interceptor()` attribute on that annotation to refer to your customized `RetryOperationsInterceptor`.

Comment: ...I have edited my question...I have implemented RetryInterceptors and invoked that interceptor in Retriable ...now how can i get the retrial count inside my method ?

Comment: ??? No, you can't do that via out-of-the-box components in the Spring Retry. The `RetryOperationsInterceptor` doesn't interfere to the method invocation. You can try via `ThreadLocal` from your custom `RetryPolicy` and get the value for that from your method.

Comment: ...Sorry I couldn't understand...Do you mean ThreadLocalContext ? Why it is very complex ? Don't we have an easy way to achieve this ?

Comment: At least I'm not aware of the easiest way. The `ThreadLocal` isn't so complex IMO. And as I said: you can't implement your requirements using Spring Retry components. You can emulate `retry count` in your own code, but that won't be based on the Spring Retry already. Only the way I see is sharing context via `ThreadLocal` variable. Something like that...

Comment: ...But In the past you said we can easily achieve it via "RetryPolicy" and we can able to get the count inside method? It wouldn't be possible ?

Comment: No, I didn't. You can get a count from `RetryPolicy`, but I didn't say that it will be done in your service method. That is fully different story...

Comment: So "ThreadLocal" is the only way to get the retrialCount inside the service method ?

Comment: That is my feeling. I don't mind any other solution.

Comment: Is it possible to access a method parameters of Retryable inside @Recover?In my case "Data" is a parameter of Retryable i want to access the data parameter inside @Recover if the all the retrials are unsuccessful. If possible means then it's a solution to my problem ?AWaiting for your response

Comment: Yes i can able to access the retryable parameters in @Recover thanks a lot for your post...

Answer (score 4):

If you are manually creating/using RetryTemplate's, you can get the current retry count from RetryContext as follows:

```
public String callWithRetry() {
    return retryTemplate.execute(new RetryCallback<String, RuntimeException>() {
        @Override
        public String doWithRetry(RetryContext context) {
            LOG.info("Retry count: {}", context.getRetryCount());
            return theService.perform();
        }
    });
}
```