# How to know if retry happening in spring retry

Tags: java, spring

I'm not adding a retry against EJB exception in listener but somehow I m thinking that retry is happening. How can I be sure if retry is happening or not.  Note: I'm using spring.retry.RetryTemplate

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42977385/spring-retry-find-the-last-retry

Comment: @user7294900 I'm seeing in log org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate doExecute RetryContext retrieved: [RetryContext: count=1, lastException=javax.ejb.EJBException: See nested exception; nested exception is: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-803, SQLSTATE=23505, SQLERRMC=3;EP4.ACT_ACCOUNT, DRIVER=4.14.146, exhausted=false]
[13/10/20 16:58:11:369 IST] 0000006d RetryTemplate 1 org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate doExecute Retry: count=1, is it mean one time retry happening?